# Error when trying to create EF model based on my existing database in ASP.net core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

A newbie in ASP.net core. In fact, a newbie in ASP.net/ web-programming.
I have encountered an error message "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 77" when trying to create EF model based on my existing database in ASP.net core 2.0.
Help is much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV0Kv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your connection string looks a bit odd, I'm not sure that colon should be there? Password=SecretPass, that's my guess.

Comment: Sorry for the late late reply. And yeah, you got that right. Turns out to be a beginner mistake of mine. It should be Password=SecretPass;